# Solaris resources for Linux administrators

Tags: linux, solaris

I will have to deal with some Solaris machines in a couple of months, but I am a born and raised Linux admin (since like, 1997). Even so, Unixes are Unixes and even if they have their differences, many things are easier to grasp.

What I would like are resources and tips from the Server Fault community about the most critical/different points so I can focus on learning those.

I already have: Solaris to Linux Migration (IBM Redbook) and Linux to Solaris Administrators Guide (Sun). Any tips are welcome :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between linux and solaris OS?](http://serverfault.com/questions/71692/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-and-solaris-os)

Comment: he only asked on the "most critical/different point", so that that it can be concentrated upon. The possible duplicates - Q:71692 is very general, if I may say so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you are maintaing a Solaris 10 machines or the older ones (9,8).
For solaris 10, some of the commands are almost the sames with Linux. If you are a bit unlucky like me you need to dig more for Solaris 8 and 9 commands, which makes a lot of different.

Important areas from my point for administering the box for Solaris 10 that a Linux Admin need to know are:

1. [SMF](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/selfheal/smf-quickstart.jsp) - Service Managemenet Framework (in linux it is services, rc and chkconfig)
2. [Jumpstart](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/features/articles/jumpstart_x86_x64.jsp) (kickstart and cloning in linux)
3. RBAC and [pfexec](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4844-Less-known-Solaris-features-pfexec.html) (something better than sudo)
4. [DTrace Toolkit](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTraceToolkit) (i put DTrace
   last although this is the main sol
   10 features, since this not high
   priority for admin, but more for
   perf troubleshooting and etc)

Other than that... read [LKSF](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/pages/lksfbook.html) book by Joerg Moellenkamp.

Answer (score 2):

I like the Unix Rosetta Stone - http://bhami.com/rosetta.html
Also covers other flavors of Unix.

System Administration Quicksheets (in PDF) - http://www.tablespace.net/quicksheet
Solaris PDF is good. Talks about basic tasks (mirroring, hardware) and includes some of Solaris 10's eccentricities.

Solaris Tips and Tricks - http://sysunconfig.net/unixtips/solaris.html
This one has some OBP stuff too which is quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good kick-start: 
http://www.sun.com/software/solaris/sysadmin_guide.pdf

And a brief introduction to Solaris: 
http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=562

An FAQ for folks coming from Linux: 
http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+documentation/newbie_faq